# Displaying Json array in echo which is nested array data in blade laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

this is my code, I want to echo all the data inside this $json.

```
$json = '{"year":"2018","month":"4","name":"Apr 2018 - Sept 2018","description":null,"code":"2018\/04","session_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-16 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"session_to_at":{"date":"2018-09-21 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"registered_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-16 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"registered_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"added_dropped_from_at":null,"added_dropped_to_at":null,"withdrew_from_at":null,"withdrew_to_at":null,"attended_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"attended_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"cw_marked_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"cw_marked_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"fe_marked_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"fe_marked_to_at":{"date":"2018-09-21 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"created_by":1,"updated_by":1,"id":2}';

$arr = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . "<br>";
    echo $value . "<br>"; // PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /workspace/Main.php on line 11
// not displaying the value
}
?>
```

the problem come went the data loop on session_from_at which have three data in array inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error because other $value is an array you cant echo it so try to check if its array or object like this :

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . "<br>";
    if(is_object($value) || is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
             echo $key2 . "<br>";
             echo $value2 . "<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: if this solution worked then accept answer.... @MuhammadRahim

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using blade. Your file name is `Main.php`
If you are using blade, I advise you to use `@foreach` instead of `foreach`.

And after `json_decode`, you still have an array inside array.

Try this code:

```php
$json = '{"year":"2018","month":"4","name":"Apr 2018 - Sept 2018","description":null,"code":"2018\/04","session_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-16 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"session_to_at":{"date":"2018-09-21 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"registered_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-16 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"registered_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"added_dropped_from_at":null,"added_dropped_to_at":null,"withdrew_from_at":null,"withdrew_to_at":null,"attended_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"attended_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"cw_marked_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-20 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"cw_marked_to_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"fe_marked_from_at":{"date":"2018-04-29 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"fe_marked_to_at":{"date":"2018-09-21 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore"},"created_by":1,"updated_by":1,"id":2}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

function echoArray($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
        echo $key . "<br>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echoArray($value);
        } else {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

echoArr($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
 $arr['year'];
 $arr['month'];
```

you do not need to use foreach.